# how to find word using a file c#

Tags: c#

My message box displays hi and his, whenever, my file has the word hello.
  My project is supposed to display the messagebox hi only,
  and for my code (rtbDisplay.Text = "\n"+"hey";) it override the hello word that 
  I type.

My project is to create a chatbox. Whenever i type in certain word, it will reply  me back with the words that i choose.

```
File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\\Users\\L31011\\Desktop\\version17\\version17\\FinalProject\\WinRecognize\\bin\\Debug\\Chat\\messages.txt", new[] { rtbType.Text });

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\L31011\\Desktop\\version17\\version17\\FinalProject\\WinRecognize\\bin\\Debug\\Chat\\messages.txt");
    rtbDisplay.Text = sr.ReadLine();
    //here
    string record;
    string input = "hello";
    string input1 = "goodbye";                                  
    try
    {
        record = sr.ReadToEnd();
        while (record != null)
        {
            if (record.Contains(input))
            {
               MessageBox.Show("hi");
               //rtbDisplay.Text = "\n"+"hey";                                           
            }
            if (record.Contains(input1))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("byebye");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("his");                                            
            }
            break;                                                 
        }                                                    
    }
    finally
    {              
        sr.Close();

    }
```

Comment: If you debug your code it is easy to figure out the issue. Did you debug  you code?

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole bunch of things that you can do to this.  First, the `@"string goes here"` construct (i.e., with an "at" sign as a preface to the string) means that there is no escaping needed.  So you don't need to double up your backslashes (I've been writing in C# since the alpha at the end of 2000, and I didn't realize that `@"c:\\some\\file.ext"` would work).  You can say either `"c:\\some\\file.ext"` or `@"c:\some\file.ext"` -- but `@"c:\\some\\file.ext"` is just weird (and too much typing).

You should read up on using `using`.  It's simpler and clearer than `try {  } finally { CloseOrDispose() }`.

Then there is what @ChetanRanpariya is talking about.  Put a breakpoint on the first `if` statement, when there is "hello" somewhere in the second line to the end.  Start single-stepping.  Notice that you step into the first message box because of the "hello".  Then continue stepping.  You don't step into the second message box, because there's no "goodbye".  But, there is an else.  See what happens next.

By the way, is this really what you want to do?  You read the first line, stick it in a text box.  Then you read lines 2 through N (all in one go, and into one string) and check to see if "hello" or "goodbye" is on any of them - all in a while loop that will only ever be executed once.

Comment: if my file has only the word hello, it will displays the messagebox hello and his. However if my file has the word hello and goodbye. it will display message box hello and byebye.

Comment: Yes, did you step through it?  You can see both behaviours as you step through.  You do understand the difference between `if (condition) {stuff}` and `if (condition) {stuff} else {other stuff}`, right? - Hint, you have one of each.

Comment: Ok it works. But what if i want to use a code(rtbDisplay.Text = "\n"+"hey";). this code basically execute when there is the word hello in the file. Such as the chatbox. However it overrides the thing i want to display in my richtextbox.

Comment: I have no idea what your comment means, sorry.  The code you show probably doesn't do what you want.  First, you call `sr.ReadLine()` and get the first line.  Then you call `sr.ReadToEnd()` and get all subsequent lines into a single string.  You take that string and enter a while loop, which will process that string (with lines 2-N) and go through the loop exactly once (unless there is no line 2).  That seems strange.  Finally, you have your `if (hello) { } if (goodbye) { } else { }` construct.  You probably want a `switch` statement (with cases for hello & goodbye, and a default for neither).